# Create an empty table and paste values - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

What I want is to create a black table in Power BI nd import data using copy paste method.
Currently I have managed to create a table and import some values using the below method:

- Home – Get Data – Common Data Sources – Click Blank Query
- = #table ({"First Column", "Second Column"}, {{1,2}, {3,4}})

[image]

Is there any alternative which allow me to create a table with many rows and paste the data in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Enter Data on the ribbon to paste tables in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Davide Bacci. Appreciate you help.